# Putting 2 fields in the same column in the Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Two of my model's fields are "title" and "summary". Right now, "title" is the first field in the ModelAdmin's list_display, which makes it link to the change page. I have some other fields in list_display as well.

I'd like to make the admin change list page display "summary" under "title" in plain, unlinked text, in the same column as "title". Is this possible? I'm using Django 1.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of. You can setup your own custom `list_display` objects to use. So for example, in your case you may do something like so:

```
def title_and_summary(obj):
    return "%s %s" % (obj.title, obj.summary)
```

Then within your admin class:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = (title_and_summary,)
```

More information can be found on the [list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) documentation.

Comment: This works perfectly! Setting allow_tags let me put in the formatting and line breaks that I needed. Thanks!